# Need to aggregate by hour and $avg not recognized

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

From a MongoDB collection storing data with time stamps I need to return a single record for each hour.

So far I have selected the set of records between two dates successfully, but I cant figure how to build the hourly record I need in the `$group` clause.

```
var myName = "CollectionName"
//schema for mongoose
var mySchema = new Schema({
    dt: Date,
    value: Number
});

var myDB = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/MYDB');

myDBObj = myDB.model(myName, evalSchema, myName);
```

The match in this aggregate call works fine, and the `$hour` creates a record for each hour in the day..  but I don't know how to recreate the a full date and get an error `"unknown group operator $avg"` ...

```
myDBObj.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { "dt": { $gt: new Date("October 13, 2010 12:00:00"), $lt: new Date("November 13, 2010 12:00:00") } }
        },{
            $group: {
            "_id": { "dt": { "$hour": "$dt" } , "price": { "$avg": "$price" }}

        }], function (err, data) { if (err) { return next(err); } res.json(data); });
```

I think I need to use `$dayOfYear` so there is different records for each hour of each day, and include a `new Date()` somewhere ...

Can someone help me do this correctly? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage works by "grouping" all data by the "key" specified for `_id`. Other fields you are actually aggregating are separate from the `_id` value and are their own field properties.

So your `$group` becomes this instead:

```js
{ "$group": {
    "_id": { "$hour": "$dt" },
    "price": { "$avg": "$price" }
}}
```

Or if you want that broken by day then make a compound key:

```js
{ "$group": {
    "_id": { 
        "day": { "$dayOfYear": "$dt" },
        "hour": { "$hour": "$dt" }
    },
    "price": { "$avg": "$price" }
}}
```

Or just use date math to produce `Date` objects rounded by hour:

```js
{ "$group": {
    "_id": { 
        "$add": [
            { "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$dt", new Date(0) ] },
                { "$mod": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$dt", new Date(0) ] },
                    1000 * 60 *60
                ]}
            ]},
            new Date(0)
         ]
    },
    "price": { "$avg": "$price" }
}}
```

Where subrtacting another date object (epoch date) from another prodces a numeric value you can round ( 1000 milliseconds, 60 seconds, 60 minutes = 1 hour ) with the applied math, and adding a number to a date object produces a date corresponding to that value.

So your problem was you had everything in the `_id`, where the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) accumulator is not recognised. All accumulators need to be specified outside of the grouping key. That is the intent.

If you want to make an accumulator value part of a grouping key ( does not seem relevant here though ), you instead follow with another group stage, referencing the field that was produced from the former.

Comment: Thank you kindly, this is exactly what I needed. It's like waking up on Christmas morning and Santa Claws is still real :)

Comment: Would you look at my next question ? It's the same query but I need to add a most common count as well as an average.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708233/need-to-find-the-most-frequently-occurring-value-of-a-field-in-a-aggregate